# Subclass of UIButton with rounded corners (swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton, subclass

Using swift, I'd like like to create a button with rounded corners. To make this re-usable, my preference is to subclass UIButton, and have come up with the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LoginButton: UIButton {

  let corner_radius : CGFloat =  4.0

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = corner_radius
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as I had hoped, even though it compiles fine. Perhaps I'm missing something - I'm very new to this!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `clipsToBounds` to ensure that the containing view isn't drawn over the corner radius:

```
self.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Thank you - what's the difference between maskToBounds and clipsToBounds?

Comment: They are essentially the same thing, I just tend to use `clipsToBounds` when I use `cornerRadius`

Answer (score 2):

You need also to turn on the `masksToBounds` on the layer:

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```